# knitr::kable(x, col.names=NULL) doesn't works when the output is a pdf

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr, kable

I need to remove the name of variables in a table produced with kable and that I will export to pdf

`kable(x, col.names = NULL)` it works when the output is in html format, but when the output is pdf it does not compile and throws an error: "add_intent_latex..."

[image]

Comment: Think I did use a workaround previously where I renamed the columns with spaces e.g. `df = df %>% rename(\` \` = Var1, \`  \` = Var2)` etc. - one space for Var1, two spaces for Var2 etc. etc. to keep colnames unique. Would this work?

Comment: Thanks. That is the interim solution that I am employing. But it is not optimal, since there is a blank space

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, I prepared a template for you:

````
---
title: "Hello World"

output:
  pdf_document: 
       latex_engine: xelatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include = FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

my_data <-  mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
my_table <- my_data %>%
        kbl(caption = "without col.names", col.names = NULL) %>%
           kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), latex_options = "hold_position")   


my_table1 <- my_data %>%
        kbl(caption = "with col.names") %>%
           kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"), latex_options = "hold_position")
```


```{r}
my_table
```

```{r}
my_table1
```
````

[image]